# Dealing with flat dependencies conflicts

Tags: .net, nuget

Take the following example:

- `John's lib` references `Foo v1.x.x`.
- `Matt's lib` references `Foo v2.x.x`.
- `Jeff's app` references both `John's lib` and `Matt's lib`,
  thus indirectly needing `Foo` on both `v1.x.x` and `v2.x.x.`.

How can I have these two versions of this same DLL on the published app?

In my *real life scenario* I ended up updating one of the libraries, since I've owned them. But the question remains.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a [binding redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) in your main application's app.config file to allow Foo v2 to be used by John's lib, assuming that Foo v1 and v2 are compatible. You would not have two versions of Foo just the latest version.

Comment: But that's the problem, they aren't compatible (hence the [*major*](http://semver.org) change).

Comment: Then updating the library is probably the best solution. Otherwise you are left doing something more complicated such as ILMerging one assembly into another, or doing some clever loading of a different version of the same assembly into the same process somehow.

Comment: So in the end, if the libraries aren't mine and there's a compatible problem, there's no solution other then those crazy workarounds of dynamic loading/statically linking the references?

Comment: Yes unfortunately so. If a library John depends on Foo v1 and Foo v2 is not compatible with Foo v1 then you would need to persuade the library author to update their NuGet package.